# Warranty forecasting - neural network based based approach?

Tags: python, neural-network, forecasting, feature-engineering, facebook-prophet

I am new here and trying to get started with a warranty forecasting problem.

I have some historical warranty claims data for automotive parts with a claim_date, associated sales data at monthly intervals, and additional details like mileage, months in service etc.

I started with aggregating the claims data to a monthly-interval dataset and used time-series/Prophet models to do some backtesting/forecasting. However, the accuracies are not high enough, even after including the monthly Sales data as a regressor and after hyperparameter tuning and so on.

I am keen to evaluate the suitability of a neural network based approach for this problem, and also try to utilise other details available to me such as mileage and months in service etc to see if it improves the forecasting accuracies. But, I don't know where is a good place to start, as I have never worked with NNs before.

I would sincerely appreciate if you could point me in the right direction, provide links to some sample code that I could get started with or any other advise that might help me get started. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! To hey started here, please post the code you've already tried. Even if it's just a tutorial you're stuck in, the assumption here is that you've tried something and are stuck on a specific, defined place. Then we can help. Good luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the date range for the data: how far back is the first year and what is the termination year? Is geographical region a dimension of interest? A model trained on data even from the last decade might perform poorly in 2020-21 if the pandemic disrupted all the previous patterns (car sales, shops shut,  https://www.bcg.com/publications/2020/covid-automotive-industry-forecasting-scenarios, etc.). It would be good to look into a first-principles model alongside working with Prophet/NNs if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! 

@Blimitless: I still don't have any code written up for the NN part. I shall give that a try and post back here with the code sample.

Salmonstrikes: The duration of the data varies from material to material and yes, there was a significant influence of covid months on the result.. I shall try putting together some code for the NN part and get back here again. Thanks!